# Spaces next to pipes

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I've seen `history | grep blah` and `history |grep blah`; and `history|grep blah` also works, though no one ever seems to use it.

Is there any significance in the spaces (e.g. piping to/from different commands requires different use of spaces), or is it always arbitrary?

Comment: Readability, mostly.

Comment: `|` pipe or `;` semicolon are used by most shell (bash, ksh, tcsh) as separator of commands. when not enclosed in quote white space before and after are irrevelent.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`bash` defines several *metacharacters*.  From `man bash`:

> **metacharacter**
>      A character that, when unquoted, separates words.  One of the following:
>                 |  & ; ( ) < > space tab

Because metacharacters separate words, it does not matter whether they are surrounded by spaces.  The pipe symbol, `|`, is a metacharacter and hence, as you noticed, it does not need spaces around it.

Note that `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, and `=` are **not** metacharacters.  Their meaning, by contrast, depends strongly on whether they are surrounded by blanks.

### Examples of when spaces are and are not needed

As you noticed, it does not matter whether `|` is surrounded by spaces.  Let us consider some examples that commonly confuse bash users.  Consider:

```
$ (date)
Sun Mar  1 12:47:07 PST 2015
```

The parens above force the `date` command to be run in a subshell.  Because `(` and `)` are metacharacters, no spaces are needed.  By contrast:

```
$ {date}
bash: {date}: command not found
```

Since `{` and `}` are *not* metacharacters, the shell treats `{date}` as one word.  Instead of looking for the `date` command, it looks for a command named `{date}`.  Because it doesn't find one, an error results.

Another common problem is the `test` command.  The following works successfully:

```
$ [ abc ] && echo Yes
Yes
```

Remove the spaces and an error occurs:

```
$ [abc] && echo Yes
bash: [abc]: command not found
```

Because `[` and `]` are *not* metacharacters, the shell treats `[.bashrc]` as a single word and the result, just like in the `date` example, is an error.

Assignment statements are also sensitive to spaces.  The following assignment is successful:

```
$ v=date
$ echo $v
date
```

Add a space and the assignment fails:

```
$ v= date
Sun Mar  1 12:55:05 PST 2015
```

In the above, the shell temporarily sets `v` to empty and then executes the `date` command.

Add a space before `=` also causes a failure but for a different reason:

```
$ v =date
bash: v: command not found
```

Here, the shell attempts to execute the command `v` with the argument `=date`.  The error is because it found no command named `v`.

Comment: I recently fell victim to the assignment statement. I had spaces before and after the `=`. Took a while to debug.

Answer (score 5):

There is one case where it can be useful to not use spaces. 
If you're not using a US-American layout, you may be forced to use some combinations like  <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to input a pipe. While this is not a problem per se, one consequence is that sometimes you also input non printing characters before or after that character. For example, on a french Macbook Pro keyboard, I have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to input `|`. When you type quickly, you can accidentally type this: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>(<kbd>L</kbd>,<kbd>Space</kbd>)

```
$ sudo dmesg | tail
zsh: command not found:  tail

echo "sudo dmesg | tail" | od -a
0000000    s   u   d   o  sp   d   m   e   s   g  sp   |   �   �   t   a
0000020    i   l  nl
```

If you're not aware that <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> inputs a different space (the non-breaking-space ([U+00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm))), the following error can be hard to understand: `zsh: command not found:  tail`

Comment: Same thing happened to me with a Macbook keyboard with Spanish layout.

Comment: Same thing with standard French keyboard: typing '|' requires AltGr and the 6 from the top. So typing | and space would sometimes produce '|' and AltGr+Space

Answer (score 3):

**Pipes** let you use the output of a program as the input of another one ...

As far as spaces , its just matter of readability / personnel preference  like  @jasonwryan mentioned.

One space-bar before and after "|" is the norm ....

You can also use it with column -t , to not just make your one liner neat , but also your output.

```
lnydex99uhc:depot_r user$ lsof | grep my | column -t
Microsoft  290  user  txt  REG  1,4  9515016  170972    /Library/Fonts/PCmyoungjo.ttf
bash       359  user  cwd  DIR  1,4  714      12246074  /Users/zatef/hw2/base/active/myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

The only significance of spaces in this case is aesthetics.
Or in other words useful to make the commands more readable to a human.