# Shell:Why do I need spaces when using pipe symbol?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

As stated in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187583/spaces-next-to-pipes) (and especially in John1024's answer, **|**
 is a metacharacter and hence, does not need spaces around it.

It makes me really confused because when I try to pipe a command I get an error "`<cmd>: command not found`". If I delete the space after the pipe symbol, the command runs perfectly. Even stranger: after successfully piping a command, I can run the same command **with** a space after the pipe symbol.

---

For instance :

- `man bash | grep foo` will return `-bash: grep: command not found`
- `man bash |grep foo` will output 3 lines containing 'foo'
- `man bash | grep foo` will *now* run and output the 3 same lines

I'd be really grateful if anyone could explain this behavior

Comment: My bad :x. Thanks for the link though !

Comment: No worries, finding that answer involved knowing it, really. It’s not an obvious problem, your question is perfectly justified.